# OO Javascript Inheritance two levels down

Tags: javascript, oop

I am inheriting an object as follows:

```
projectile.prototype = Object.create(interactiveElement.prototype);
function projectile(){
    interactiveElement.call(this);
}
```

interactiveElement has a method draw, defined.

```
interactiveElement.prototype.draw = function(){

}
```

when I call it like this it works fine

```
var myArrow = new projectile();
myArrow.draw();
```

but if inherit once more and call the draw method from this instead:

```
arrow.prototype = Object.create(projectile.prototype);
function arrow(){
    projectile.call(this);
}

var myArrow = new arrow();
myArrow.draw();
```

I then get the error "arrow has no method 'draw'". Can you only inherit once? and am I doing it correctly at all?

Comment: don't have time for a big answer, check out this article about [javaScript classical inheritance](http://metadea.de/V/)

Comment: If you have an error, it's probably somewhere else, because the code you've submitted works: http://jsbin.com/erOkaVI/1/edit?js,console

Comment: It was down to the order in which I created the objects, putting arrow after projectile fixed this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example (http://jsfiddle.net/2n62J/)

```
function interactiveElement() {
}

interactiveElement.prototype.draw = function(){
    console.log('draw');
};

function projectile() {
    interactiveElement.call(this);
}

projectile.prototype = Object.create(interactiveElement.prototype);
projectile.prototype.fire = function() {
    console.log('projectile fire');
};

function arrow() {
    projectile.call(this);
}
arrow.prototype = Object.create(projectile.prototype);
arrow.prototype.fire = function() {
    projectile.prototype.fire.call(this); // if you want to call the parent function
    console.log('arrow fire');
};

var myArrow = new projectile();
myArrow.draw();
myArrow.fire();

var myArrow2 = new arrow();
myArrow2.draw();
myArrow2.fire();
```

Comment: Could you explain what was changed?

Comment: I believe it was the order in which objects where created was the problem.

Comment: Yes, the ordering is important. Be sure to create your prototype after the function definition.

Comment: This doesn't matter, because function declaration are hoisted. As far as I see you didn't have to change anything, because the code in the question was already working.